# Magento 2 : We cant place the order : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer your_db_user@% does not exist

Tags: magento, magento2, checkout

I have migrated a magento 2 site to a new server and afte that the place order is broken.

It is giving the below error :

We cant place the order : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1449 The user specified as a definer your_db_user@% does not exist, query was: UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item`

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix this is to remove the DEFINER statements from your mysql dump then reimport the data into the server.

Comment: Since the data was huge so i did it by using PHPMYADMIN. It worked.. Thanks mailman :)